# How can I change the color of "Nodeclipse Console"?

Tags: eclipse, nodeclipse

i changed a dark theme with dark-background on Eclipse,
Console's background is dark too.
But "Nodeclipse Console" still is crazy white.
My eyes is hurt! help me please...

Answer (score 0):

It should have been OK

At least with Dark theme.

There's nothing special with Nodeclipse Console it is just instance of Eclipse Console and everything that applies is to work similar.

[image]

Raise issue on https://github.com/nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/ given full details.

Comment: sir, it's OK on Moonrise UI Theme, but not OK on a Dark "Jeeeyul's Themes"

Comment: Dark is Moonrise that was contributed to and is continued within Eclipse Foundation, raise bug on https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi against Platform/Workbench. Picture is for Dark within 4.4.0M5